# API Response - How to handle response in React

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to work with an API that sends out a list of questions to create a question set. This is the response from the API:

```json
{"questionSetItems":[[1,"From which date would you like your insurance to start from?","This is the date on which you want the policy to begin. The policy will not pay for any claims which occur prior to this date.","Dropdown",[],"",false],[2,"What is your title?","","DropDown",[],"",false],[3,"What is your title?","","DropDown",[],"",false],[4,"What is your forename?","","Edit",[],"",false],[5,"What is your surname?","","Edit",[],"",false],[6,"What is your date of birth?","","Date",[],"",false],[7,"You and your spouse or partner are not: <br\/>Professional Sportspeople<br\/>Professional Entertainers<br\/>Professional Gamblers<br\/>Moneylenders or Pawnbrokers<br\/>Bailiffs or Bodyguards<br\/>Bar Managers<br\/>Car Dealers\/Salespeople<br\/>Circus or Fairground Employees\/Owners<br\/>Clairvoyants, Tarot Readers or Palmistry Experts<br\/>Croupiers, Gaming Club Managers\/Proprietors<br\/>Diamond or Metal Dealers<br\/>Exotic Dancers<br\/>Jewellers or Jewellery Consultants<br\/>Street\/Market Traders<br\/>Tattooists<br\/>Student<br\/>Unemployed\/In voluntary employment<br\/><br\/>Please confirm that you agree to the above statements.","","YesNo",["inputEmploymentYes","inputEmploymentNo"],"",true],[8,"Please select the relevant employment types for both you and your spouse or partner","","ButtonList",["inputSportspeople","inputEntertainers","inputGamblers","inputBar","inputBailiffs","inputMoneyLender","inputTarot","inputCircus","inputCar","inputExotic","inputDiamond","inputCroupiers","inputTattooists","inputStreet","inputJewellers","inputVoluntary","inputUnemployed","inputOther","inputStudent"],"partnerType",false],[9,"Do you need to add a joint policyholder?","","YesNo",["inputJointHolderYes","inputJointHolderNo"],"",true]],"headerLogo":"","cOB":"STDH","isLastPage":false}
```

How to look through the array in React?

Comment: What do you mean _"look through the array"_? For what? And what about this is specific to React, not just basic JS? Please give a [mre] showing what you've tried and the specific problem with it.

Comment: Do you mean to render the array that you get in response from the API ?

Comment: Was meant to say Loop - and yes i want to render the array from the response.

Answer (score -1):

---

yo
u can use like this .u can keep it in a variable name and u can check in which key ur getting the  array of datas , then you can map the fields and u will get data

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M8mJZ.png)

Comment: Thanks for your help earlier today.  The Array creates a question set with some questions hidden dependent on responses to other questions.  Whats the best way to show/hide questions?  I was looking at setting the state onClick but as i wont know which questions required show/hide functionality im not sure how i manage the states of multiple divs that im not going to be aware of until the page loads.  Hope this makes sense and would appreciate some more help if possibe?